# How to upload files to sharepoint from java application?

Tags: java, spring, web, sharepoint, java-11

Is there any java interfaces or libraries to upload files to Share point ?
I have to download files from remote server and upload the downloaded files to Share point location.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/265449

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any Java libraries but you can always use SharePoint rest API's to achieve the file upload functionality. This would require to authenticate your API calls. Please check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250827/download-and-upload-file-from-share-point-using-java-rest-api-call